# Is there no install file for Android Studio

Tags: windows-8, android-studio

I am looking to install Android Studio but all I can find is the .zip file on the site that has the exe's. Is there no install file that adds all the shortcuts and dependencies?

Comment: What do you mean? You download a ~360MB .exe file which is the installer.

Comment: @RsyaStudios could you please paste the link?

Answer (score 2):

I see what you mean now. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700800/android-studio-no-installation-wizard):

> Turns out that Android Studio is now portable - like Eclipse. In other words, there is no installing, **you just get the zip file, which contains everything you need,** such as the executables that run Android Studio. You'll need to store this folder somewhere relevant and **create a shortcut to the studio(64).exe** file to run it from desktop/start menu.

The SDK is also no longer bundled with Android Studio, so that will need to be downloaded separately, as the zip file only contains the IDE and not the Android SDK.

[Link to SDK](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe).

You will then point Android Studio to your SDK installation location.

**INFO:** Apparently Google has also changed all of the previous versions to [zip files](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/beta).
[Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727531/android-studio-not-including-sdk).
When you start Android Studio, it won't let you create a new project until you configure the SDK location.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764174/installing-new-android-studio-beta-v-0-8-14/26764657#26764657)

Comment: Yeah that is what I have been doing but I was hoping that they had a bundle somewhere.

Comment: Yeah me too.. but I guess everything in a zip file is convenient too. It won't leave too much footprints on my computer - downside is the extra hassle for the SDK of course.